# Deprecated URL retrieve functions and hooks

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to have a progress indication on the console when downloading a file from a URL. This can be done with a report hook in the `urllib.request.urlretrieve` function. But this is a legacy interface and the documentation states it may be deprecated at some point.

Is there a way to indicate progress to the user with some sort of hook using a URL retrieval function that is up to date and current in Python 3.5, and not legacy or deprecated?